# How can I blend two colors to create a translucent effect?

Tags: c++, graphics

If I have two RGBA values, defined as `r1 -> a1`, `r2 -> a2`, how can I merge/blend the colors to create an effect that looks like translucency? I need it to look like it's almost see-through, as shown in the image below:

[image: Translucent Shapes]

I have seen examples where it produces something like: `white + red = pink` but that isn't the effect I'm looking for, I'm looking for something that looks more like this image.

Comment: I think I saw this question yesterday.

Comment: May have, but the answer I was given was of no help.

Comment: Have you considered this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing

Comment: @Quinchilion I have read it, I can make little sense of it, though.

Comment: What I'm looking for is the 'ADD' operator on here.